# jquery mouseenter do this, mouseleave do that, click do this and stop mouseenter/mouseleave events

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, mouseenter, mouseleave

I am trying to have an image attribute source replaced on mouse enter mouse leave event. And when clicked, the image should stay as active. I need the mouseleave event to stop after clicking has been made. So far the mouseeleave still continues after clicking, switching back the image , here is the code below:

```
<script>
    jQuery('.paypal').mouseenter(function(){
        jQuery('.paypal').attr('src','http://url-to-my-active-image.jpg');?>');
    }),
    jQuery('.paypal').mouseleave(function(){
        jQuery('.paypal').attr('src','http://url-to-my-inactive-image.jpg');
    }),
    jQuery('.paypal').click(function(){
        jQuery('.paypal').css('opacity','1');
    });
</script>
```

How can I achieve that?.

Comment: Possible duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628768/stop-mouseleave-when-clicked-on-an-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just turn [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) the mouseleave when you click with:

```
jQuery('.paypal').click(function(){
    jQuery('.paypal').css('opacity','1').off('mouseleave');
});
```

Comment: jQuery('.paypal') seems ripe for caching as well, since it's used six times in the original example.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution seems to be to add a class on click, and then check for the presence of that class on mouseleave; if it's there, do nothing.

```
<script>
    jQuery('.paypal').mouseenter(function(){
        jQuery('.paypal').attr('src','http://url-to-my-active-image.jpg');?>');
    }),
    jQuery('.paypal').mouseleave(function(){
        if(!jQuery('.paypal').hasClass('selected')){
            jQuery('.paypal').attr('src','http://url-to-my-inactive-image.jpg');
        }
    }),
    jQuery('.paypal').click(function(){
        jQuery('.paypal').css('opacity','1').addClass('selected');
    });
</script>
```

@j08691's answer is probably easier to maintain, especially if you're using a recent version of jQuery (1.7 or higher).

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the `mouseleave` handler inside the `click` handler by using `off`:

```
jQuery('.paypal').click(function() {
    jQuery('.paypal').css('opacity', '1');
    jQuery('.paypal').off('mouseleave');
});
```