# How to not trigger mouseleave on clicked elements

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm making a category that has five menus and changes its color to '#4B654A' when clicked or mouseentered.
If mouseleave happens, the color should go back to '#C7C7C7' unless it is clicked.

```
// code for mouseenter and mouseleave function

$('.big-category').each(function(i){
    var selected = $('.big-category').eq(i);

    $(this).on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            selected.find('.category-text').css('color', '#4B654A');
            selected.find('path').attr('fill', '#4B654A');
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            selected.find('.category-text').css('color', '#C7C7C7');
            selected.find('path').attr('fill', '#C7C7C7');
        }
    });
});


// code for click function

$('.big-category a').click(function() {
    $('.big-category a').css('color', '#C7C7C7');
    $(this).css('color', '#4B654A');
});
```

I want clicked elements to stay with the color '#4B654A' until next click on other elements happens,however, mouseleave function won't let me.
I will be much appreciated with your advice!

Comment: Can you please add your html, it's hard to give you a good answer without

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628768/stop-mouseleave-when-clicked-on-an-object